# Gradle Sync issues in Android Studio: intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Equal objects must have equal hashcodes

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to sync my project in Android Studio but getting a weird error. Essentially I have created a new branch of my code which has a new application Id and a few "skin" based assets but essentially the same codebase and same build.gradle files with the exception of the ApplicationId.

The project builds succesfully but Android studio will not sync gradle. In the Android Studio I get the following. Any help would be appreciated (apologies for the formatting. not a wizard with stack trace).

thanks

I have tried the usual:

- remove the .gradle directory
- invalidate caches and restart
- reinstall node modules
- check all SDKs are downloaded
- tried different gradle plugin and version combinations including latest ones

nothing makes a difference. In addition, if I try to generate a bundle in AS it complains that the gradle plugin needs to be more than version 3.20 (which it is) and won't let me do anything. I'm not sure if this is also to do with syncing or not or even related. Note: I can assemble and bundle at the command line

and in the idea.log I get the following:

```
/Users/mm186148/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/caches/clangd_modules/7026b673 
2022-10-13 10:37:00,267 [  32958]   INFO - ngd.lsp.ClangDaemonContextImpl - Using clangd from: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/c-clangd/bin/clang/mac/clangd 
2022-10-13 10:37:00,628 [  33319]   INFO - dle.roots.GradleBuildRootIndex - /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android: null -> org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.New@17f49ccc 
2022-10-13 10:37:01,325 [  34016]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (trace_hash = -2006292609) 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.logRootChanges(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.synchronizeRoots(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:296)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.fireRootsChangedEvent(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:459)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$1.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$1.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.makeRootsChange(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:431)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.project.ProjectRootManagerBridge.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerBridge.kt:145)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.project.ProjectRootManagerBridge.access$fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerBridge.kt:29)
    at com.intellij.workspaceModel.ide.impl.legacyBridge.project.ProjectRootManagerBridge$JdkChangeListener.rootSetChanged(ProjectRootManagerBridge.kt:273)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at  at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:746)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:969)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:839)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:449)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:448)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:496)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
2022-10-13 10:37:01,449 [  34140]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = -2006292609) 
2022-10-13 10:37:01,454 [  34145]   INFO - dle.roots.GradleBuildRootIndex - /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.New@17f49ccc -> org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.New@ba914c4 
/Users/mm186148/Library/Logs/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/threadDumps-freeze-20221013-103709-AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675-8sec 
2022-10-13 10:37:12,911 [  45602]   WARN - Container.ComponentManagerImpl - Do not use constructor injection (requestorClass=com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.build.invoker.GradleBuildInvokerImpl) 
2022-10-13 10:37:13,134 [  45825]   INFO - ProjectRootPostStartUpActivity - /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false  
2022-10-13 10:39:36,907 [ 189598]   INFO - ta.index.VcsLogPersistentIndex - Indexing 331 commits in roundtables 
2022-10-13 10:39:37,158 [ 189849]   INFO - ativeWorkspaceModificationTask - NDK support for project 'engfanzone' is disabled because the project doesn't contain any valid native configurations. 
2022-10-13 10:39:37,599 [ 190290]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android] resolution task started 
2022-10-13 10:39:37,906 [ 190597]   INFO - adleSyncState$SyncStateUpdater - onStart(RESOLVE_PROJECT:0, /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android) 
2022-10-13 10:39:37,907 [ 190598]   INFO - cState$SyncStateUpdaterService - trackTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:0, /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android) 
2022-10-13 10:39:37,908 [ 190599]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started single-variant (TRIGGER_PROJECT_REOPEN) sync with Gradle for project 'engfanzone'. 
2022-10-13 10:39:38,092 [ 190783]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Clearing project build data because the project does not exist or was not opened for more than 30 days: /Users/mm186148/Library/Caches/Google/AndroidStudio2021.1/compile-server/lecolclubapp_201189 
2022-10-13 10:39:38,686 [ 191377]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/mm186148/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-11.54.25 
2022-10-13 10:39:38,688 [ 191379]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/mm186148/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-11.54.25 
2022-10-13 10:39:38,891 [ 191582]   INFO -                         STDOUT - Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip 
2022-10-13 10:39:39,469 [ 192160]   INFO - ta.index.VcsLogPersistentIndex - 2.554s for indexing 331 new commits out of 331 in roundtables 
2022-10-13 10:39:56,155 [ 208846]   INFO -                         STDOUT - ............................................................................................................................................... 
2022-10-13 10:40:04,292 [ 216983]   INFO - oject.common.GradleInitScripts - init script file sync.studio.tooling contents "initscript {\n    dependencies {\n        classpath files(['/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android.jar', '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.4.32.jar'])\n    }\n}\nallprojects {\n    apply plugin: com.android.ide.gradle.model.builder.AndroidStudioToolingPlugin\n}\n" 
2022-10-13 10:40:04,502 [ 217193]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: --init-script /private/var/folders/0p/qnkh1f_s2dz7mgf6wqw14scm2typ_0/T/ijmapper.gradle -Didea.sync.active=true -Porg.gradle.kotlin.dsl.provider.cid=173192732929312 --init-script /private/var/folders/0p/qnkh1f_s2dz7mgf6wqw14scm2typ_0/T/sync.studio.tooling.gradle -Djava.awt.headless=true --stacktrace -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=2021.1.1 Patch 3 -Pandroid.injected.build.model.disable.src.download=true -Pidea.gradle.do.not.build.tasks=true -Dorg.gradle.internal.GradleProjectBuilderOptions=omit_all_tasks --init-script /private/var/folders/0p/qnkh1f_s2dz7mgf6wqw14scm2typ_0/T/ijinit.gradle 
2022-10-13 10:54:11,068 [1063759]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.1.3 
2022-10-13 10:54:11,219 [1063910]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.1.3 
2022-10-13 10:54:11,220 [1063911]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.1.3 
2022-10-13 10:54:11,236 [1063927]   INFO - testKnownPluginVersionProvider - 'gradle' plugin missing from the offline Maven repo, will use default 7.1.3 
 
2022-10-13 10:54:17,158 [1069849]   INFO - adleSyncState$SyncStateUpdater - onSuccess(RESOLVE_PROJECT:0) 
2022-10-13 10:54:17,197 [1069888]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started setup of project 'engfanzone'. 
2022-10-13 10:54:18,327 [1071018]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/mm186148/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-11.54.25 
2022-10-13 10:54:18,432 [1071123]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinInitScript] using classpath: /Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-api-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20-patched-for-gradle-6.9.jar 
2022-10-13 10:54:21,084 [1073775]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/mm186148/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-11.54.25 
2022-10-13 10:54:21,117 [1073808]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinSettingsScript] using classpath: /Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-api-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20-patched-for-gradle-6.9.jar 
2022-10-13 10:54:21,340 [1074031]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /Users/mm186148/.asdf/installs/java/zulu-11.54.25 
2022-10-13 10:54:21,341 [1074032]   INFO - g.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.script - [KOTLIN_SCRIPTING] Loading script definitions [org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.KotlinBuildScript] using classpath: /Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-api-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-tooling-models-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-kotlin-dsl-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/gradle-core-6.9.jar:/Users/mm186148/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-6.9-all/dooywd8nv05k16orzxge2b1bs/gradle-6.9/lib/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.4.20-patched-for-gradle-6.9.jar 
2022-10-13 10:54:21,971 [1074662]   INFO - dle.roots.GradleBuildRootIndex - /Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android: org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.New@ba914c4 -> org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.scripting.gradle.roots.Imported@74e3c07c 
2022-10-13 10:54:24,078 [1076769]   INFO - System.util.ExternalSystemUtil - External project [/Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android] resolution task executed in 886475 ms. 
2022-10-13 10:54:26,494 [1079185]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - project roots have changed (trace_hash = -1195913871) 
java.lang.Throwable
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.logRootChanges(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.synchronizeRoots(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:296)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerComponent.fireRootsChangedEvent(ProjectRootManagerComponent.java:201)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:459)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$1.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:146)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$1.fireRootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:143)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:113)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl$BatchSession.rootsChanged(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:121)
    at com.intellij.openapi.roots.impl.ProjectRootManagerImpl.makeRootsChange(ProjectRootManagerImpl.java:431)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.ucache.ScriptClassRootsUpdater$notifyRootsChanged$1$1.invoke(ScriptClassRootsUpdater.kt:233)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.core.script.ucache.ScriptClassRootsUpdater$notifyRootsChanged$1$1.invoke(ScriptClassRootsUpdater.kt:228)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt.runWriteAction$lambda-1(ApplicationUtils.kt:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$runWriteAction$15(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteActionWithClass(ApplicationImpl.java:953)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:974)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.util.application.ApplicationUtilsKt.runWriteAction(ApplicationUtils.kt:21)
    at    2022-10-13 10:54:35,287 [1087978]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:39,232 [1091923]   WARN - ctionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater - 2009ms to expand group child Debug 
2022-10-13 10:54:39,232 [1091923]   WARN - ctionSystem.impl.ActionUpdater - 2073ms to expand group child RunnerActionsTouchbar 
2022-10-13 10:54:39,583 [1092274]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:41,311 [1094002]   INFO - rationStore.ComponentStoreImpl - Saving Project(name=engfanzone, containerState=COMPONENT_CREATED, componentStore=/Users/mm186148/nodeprojects/roundtables/android)DebuggerManager took 31 ms, ProjectView took 19 ms, RunManager took 17 ms, ToolWindowManager took 11 ms, XDebuggerManager took 15 ms, sourceFolderManager took 79 ms 
2022-10-13 10:54:41,312 [1094003]   INFO - mponents.impl.stores.StoreUtil - saveProjectsAndApp took 17038 ms 
2022-10-13 10:54:41,460 [1094151]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,125 [1101816]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,153 [1101844]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,247 [1101938]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,263 [1101954]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,336 [1102027]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,407 [1102098]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,425 [1102116]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,441 [1102132]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,459 [1102150]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,478 [1102169]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,503 [1102194]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,522 [1102213]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,540 [1102231]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,555 [1102246]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,573 [1102264]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,588 [1102279]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,604 [1102295]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,629 [1102320]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,647 [1102338]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,676 [1102367]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:49,702 [1102393]   INFO - pl.ProjectRootManagerComponent - some project roots were removed (stacktrace has been already reported with trace_hash = 734090117) 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,740 [1107431]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's documentation. object #1 =WeakKey(:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links, 376698834) (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap$WeakKey), hashCode=376698834; object #2 =WeakKey(:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links, -1968948302) (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap$WeakKey), hashCode=-1968948302 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Equal objects must have equal hashcodes. During rehashing, Trove discovered that the following two objects claim to be equal (as in java.lang.Object.equals() or TObjectHashingStrategy.equals()) but their hashCodes (or those calculated by your TObjectHashingStrategy) are not equal.This violates the general contract of java.lang.Object.hashCode().  See bullet point two in that method's documentation. object #1 =WeakKey(:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links, 376698834) (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap$WeakKey), hashCode=376698834; object #2 =WeakKey(:react-native-firebase_dynamic-links, -1968948302) (class com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap$WeakKey), hashCode=-1968948302
    at gnu.trove.TObjectHash.throwObjectContractViolation(TObjectHash.java:331)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.RefHashMap$MyMap.rehash(RefHashMap.java:100)
    at gnu.trove.THash.postInsertHook(THash.java:285)
    at gnu.trove.THashMap.put(THashMap.java:174)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.RefHashMap.putKey(RefHashMap.java:179)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.RefHashMap.put(RefHashMap.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.containers.WeakHashMap.put(WeakHashMap.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.IdeModelsProviderImpl.findIdeModule(IdeModelsProviderImpl.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.AbstractDependencyDataService.lambda$computeOrphanData$0(AbstractDependencyDataService.java:88)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.AbstractDependencyDataService.removeData(AbstractDependencyDataService.java:138)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.doImportData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:265)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:120)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.project.manage.ProjectDataManagerImpl.importData(ProjectDataManagerImpl.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.populateProject(IdeaSyncPopulateProjectTask.java:53)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.doPopulateProject(ProjectSetUpTask.java:54)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask.onSuccess(ProjectSetUpTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.handExecutionResult(ExternalSystemUtil.java:592)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.executeImpl(ExternalSystemUtil.java:572)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.lambda$execute$1(ExternalSystemUtil.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceHeavyActivities.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceHeavyActivities.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbServiceImpl.suspendIndexingAndRun(DumbServiceImpl.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$2.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:674)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:998)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcessWithProgressAsync$5(CoreProgressManager.java:497)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$3(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$2(CoreProgressManager.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:688)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:634)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:64)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:165)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressRunner.lambda$submit$4(ProgressRunner.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1700)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:668)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$PrivilegedThreadFactory$1.run(Executors.java:665)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-10-13 10:54:54,741 [1107432]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Started 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,742 [1107433]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 3  Build #AI-211.7628.21.2111.8309675 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,746 [1107437]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - JDK: 11.0.11; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o. 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,747 [1107438]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - OS: Mac OS X 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,747 [1107438]  ERROR - intellij.openapi.progress.Task - Last Action:  
2022-10-13 10:54:54,748 [1107439]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Scanning: use 7 scanning threads 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,837 [1107528]   INFO - cState$SyncStateUpdaterService - stopTrackingTask(RESOLVE_PROJECT:0) 
2022-10-13 10:54:54,843 [1107534]   WARN - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: Sync failed: reason unknown (15 m 16 s 932 ms)
```

Comment: Good News. I upgraded Andorid Studio and it seemed to solved the issue. clearly some kind of IDE issue. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved by upgrading/reinstalling Android Studio.